# Entityobject and foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use entity framework with sqlserver database.
The table, that is represented by EntityObject contains  foreign keys to another tables.
For example:

```
ArticleID|ArticleTitle|ArticleBody|CategoryID (key to another table)
```

I use this query to return the Enityobject:

```
 public Article GetArticleById(int id)
 {
        var article = Articlerctx.Articles.Where(o=>o.ArticleID==id).FirstOrDefault();          
        return article;
 }
```

But I want to return also fields from other table (join, on some fileds not all of them).

Do I need to define new  class for that purpose(class that have corresponded fields)?

and return it like:

```
 public ArticleFull GetArticleById(int id)
 {
    var ret = (from article in Articlerctx.Articles
                  select new ArticleFull
                  {
                     ArticleID = article.ArticleID,
                     Title = article.Title,
                     CategoryTitle = article.Articles_Categories.Title,
                   }).Where(o => o.ArticleID == id).FirstOrDefault();
     return ret;
 }
```

It would be be crazy to deine new classes for every field...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [.Include() extension](http://naspinski.net/post/Getting-Foreign-Key-Values-with-Linq-to-Entities.aspx).

Comment: this works, but is it efficient enough to include  whole table just for one field that  i need? or is it same using new class with select new...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly then you need to enable [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) in your EF(By Default it is true).

If you use LazyLoading option then you can access the values of reference table like,

```
           EntityContext Context = new EntityContext();

           Context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = True;//by default it is true

           var article = Articlerctx.Articles.Where(o=>o.ArticleID==id).FirstOrDefault();          

           Article.Category.Id or any other field from category.
```

If you don't want to use LazyLoading() option then answer by @naspinski will work.

Comment: there is no EnableLzyLoading property in context... anyway it won't work if you don't include other table